# Сервисные сообщения от Discord

Tags: discord, discord.py, discord-api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привет! Кто-то может подсказать как отловить сервисные сообщения в Discord?
Я использую Discord.Net (C#) что бы слушать сообщения которые приходят на сервер, где сидят разные боты. И мне надо знать когда на канале появляются такого рода ошибки ( Как на скрине)

**Меня устроит решение на любой библиотеке и языке, или через API запрос, это не имеет особо значения.**

```
        _discordClient.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
        _discordClient.MessageUpdated += MessageUpdated;
        _discordClient.SlashCommandExecuted += _discordClient_SlashCommandExecuted;
        _discordClient.UserCommandExecuted += _discordClient_UserCommandExecuted;
        _discordClient.MessageCommandExecuted += _discordClient_MessageCommandExecuted;
```

Эта пачка никак не реагирует на сервисные.

.MessageReceived ловит сообщения которые имеют ID как я понял. Сервисные же их не имеют, а ловить ой как хочется. Очень жду прям ответов ))
Да, права бота - Admin, и все Интенты.ALL

Comment: А это не уровень бота, а клиента. Вы сейчас условно спрашиваете "Как ботом мне получить приватное сообщение пользователя". Приватные сообщения, на то и приватные, что другие их не видят. Это кстати не системные сообщения, а [эфемерные сообщения](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500000580222-Ephemeral-Messages-FAQ). Если ваше приложение шлет сообщение клиенту, тогда тет-а-тет у вас к ним доступ есть (и то не уверен, можно редактировать или нет), но чужих людей, уж извините.

Comment: Значит надо сделать бота с теми же командами что и у бота к которому я обращаюсь сейчас, после чего начать писать сообщения к моему боту, он в свою очередь будет врапить первого, если команда указана без ошибок. А если с ошибкой, то я смогу видимо отловить ее? Мой бот получается будет инициатором вызова ошибки. И эфимерное сообщение даже не понадобится. Там наверняка есть события успешного и не успешного выполнения slash команд ( я так неуверенно говорю, тк не особо знаком с дискордом)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я просто через Http шлю запрос левому боту, тк нужна автоматизация вне Discord. И пользователь может ввести неверный запрос, а тк мой сервер просто слушает бота и возвращает ответы юзеру, то  о том, что там ошибка была узнать можно лишь кривыми способами, вроде чтения сообщений канала и поиска в нём сообщения от пользователя, и если не нашел, значит ошибка. Но это что-то корявое как по мне)